# Read error - innfinitlly while readig

Tags: c++

At that Code i get a problem. It reads innfinitlly and i don't know how to stop it

```
while(scanf("%d",&v[++n])){
    fr[v[n]]++;
}
```

I need to stop it when it is reading
that is the input file:

```
5 6 4 1 2
5 7 2
```

the output file is:

```
2 5
```

Comment: what is the value of `n` at the beginning?

Comment: also, how is the output file created? there are no `printf` calls

Comment: all the values are type int. the read is the problem. at that while is getting an innfinitlly reading.

Comment: oh, now I understand, at first I thought you were reading infinity (like dividing by zero, or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) might return [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/) which generally is -1 value, `-1` used in while will result in true - so you will have never ending loop.

So the correct code will be:

```
while(scanf("%d",&v[++n]) == 1){
                          ^^^^ ---- 1 indicates number of items that 
                                    were filled in argument list
```

Comment: Can you explain that, please? I don't understand what is EOF

Comment: EOF is a macro definition which is retuned by scanf if input stream ends